# How to add up int pointer values in a linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list

I've been working at this homework assignment for awhile and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. How my program is suppose to work:
User enters as many positive numbers as they so desire,
Numbers are in a linked list,
Numbers entered should be added up,
Divide by the amount of numbers entered,
Resulting in the average,
However, it's not working out as I had intended and I've been playing with this for over 3 hours now. I'd contact my teacher but she hasn't responded to my last message still and I need assistance right away. Thanks in advance.

**Note: I need to traverse the list to add up all the entered numbers and count the number of nodes.**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num, total, num_entries = 1;

struct number_node
{
 int number;
 number_node *next;
};

number_node *head_ptr;
number_node *current_ptr;

int get_number_data(int &number);
void add_node(int &number);
void move_current_to_end();
void display_avg();
void delete_list();

int main()
{
 if(get_number_data(num))
 {
  head_ptr = new number_node;
  head_ptr->number = num;
  head_ptr->next = NULL;

  while(get_number_data(num))
  {
   add_node(num);
  }
  display_avg();
  delete_list();
 }

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

int get_number_data(int &number)
{
 int keep_data = 1;

 cout << "Enter a positive number (Enter a negative number to stop): ";
 cin >> num;
 if(num < 0)
 {
  keep_data = 0;
 }

 return(keep_data);
}

void add_node(int &number)
{
 number_node *new_rec_ptr;

 new_rec_ptr = new number_node;

 new_rec_ptr->number = num;
 new_rec_ptr->next = NULL;

 move_current_to_end();
 current_ptr->next = new_rec_ptr;
}

void move_current_to_end()
{
 current_ptr = head_ptr;
 num_entries++;

 while(current_ptr->next != NULL)
 {
  current_ptr = current_ptr->next;
  total = current_ptr->number + total;
 }
}

void display_avg()
{
 current_ptr = head_ptr;
 cout << "Average = " << total / num_entries << endl;
}

void delete_list()
{
 number_node *temp_ptr;

 current_ptr = head_ptr;

 do
 {
  temp_ptr = current_ptr->next;

  delete current_ptr;

  current_ptr = temp_ptr;
 }
 while(temp_ptr != NULL);
}
```

Comment: You should give a better description of the problems than "it's not working out". What doesn't work? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Where do you have problems?

Answer (score 3):

Right now you're mixing your data structure (linked list) with what you intend to use it for. Consider splitting your logic into:

- Your I/O code.
- The linked list implementation.
- A function that takes a linked list, and computes the average.

Comment: Right now, whenever you add a node you are also adding the value of that node to the total (in `move_current_to_end` by proxy of `add_node`). Instead, `add_node` should only add the node to the list - the actual total/length calculation should be done after everything has been added to the list. See Jonathan's answer for accomplishing the latter part.

Comment: hm... I can't use a for loop in this assignment though... I have to work with what I've got there... EDIT: didn't realize that enter submitted, anyways, I need to have the thing calculate the total and number of nodes while it's traversing.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by recursion.

Comment: A function that calls itself with a terminating base case to break the cycle.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use recursion. That's a dreadful idea.

Comment: @TonyK: Since a linked list is a recursive data structure (in fact, it's pretty much the standard recursive data structure given its prevalence in functional programming) a recursive algorithm is generally preferable to loop, as it is often more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of other stuff there and you didn't say what your code does, but I'd do something like this (untested):

```
 int count = 0;
 int total = 0;

 for (ptr = head_ptr; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
 {
     total += ptr->number;
     count++;
 }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to "traverse" the list in order to total the numbers entered and count the number of nodes in the list. Thus, my big dilemma...

Comment: I don't understand. My code does traverse the list, it does count the number of nodes, and it also adds the sum - ???

Comment: but I can't use a for loop, I have to use what I've got

Comment: According to you, what you've got isn't working. So I assumed you needed to write it differently. Your version is overly complex. Unfortunately, so is your description. As I solve one problem, you raise another.

Comment: I just have to have it figure out the total and and # of nodes using those functions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this won't help you with your homework, but here is a C++ STL program that satisfies your requirements:

- As many inputs as the user desires
- Numbers are stored in a linked list
- Numbers are added up
- Calculates and displays average

Good luck with your class.

```
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
  std::list<double> l;

  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>(std::cin),
    std::istream_iterator<double>(),
    std::insert_iterator<std::list<double> >(l, l.begin()));

  size_t size = l.size();
  if(size)
    std::cout << std::accumulate(l.begin(), l.end(), 0.0) / l.size()
      << std::endl;
}
```

~

Answer (score 0):

Apologies: would have attached a comment to ask this introductory question. But apparently you need a higher rep than i currently have to do so.

@Brandon. Can i get you to clearly state that it is these functions:

int get_number_data(int &number)

void add_node(int &number)

void move_current_to_end()

void display_avg()

and only these that you are allowed to use? (And i quote you: "I just have to have it figure out the total and and # of nodes using those functions"

If so. Why? Have they been specified by your lecturer?